# $\int_{\Omega\setminus A_n}f\;d\mu\to\int_\Omega f\;d\mu$ for all measurable $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space
- $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ such that $A_n\downarrow\emptyset$, i.e. $A_n\supseteq A_{n+1}$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n=\emptyset$
- $f\in\mathcal{L^1}(\mu)$

I tink we should be able to prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega\setminus A_n}f\;d\mu=\int_\Omega f\;d\mu\tag{1}$$ and I think we can do so in the following way:

- Let $f_n:=1_{\Omega\setminus A_n}f$
- Obviously, we've got $$f_n^\pm\le f_{n+1}^\pm\tag{2}$$ where $x^+:=\max(x,0)$ and $x^-:=\max(-x,0)$ denote the positive and negative part of $x\in\mathbb{R}$, respectively.
- If we could show $f_n^\pm\uparrow f^\pm$, i.e. $f_n^\pm\le f_{n+1}^\pm$ and $f_n^\pm\to f$ for $n\to\infty$, $(1)$ would follow from the *Monotone convergence theorem*
- Clearly, we can write $$f_n^+=f^+-1_{A_n}f^+$$
- So, we are done, if we can show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}1_{A_n}f^+=1_\emptyset f\tag{3}^+$$ which should be obviously true

Have I missed something? Do we need that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite or $\mu(A_n)<\infty$

Comment: There don't seem to be any $\infty$ - $\infty$'s here so likely not for the second

Answer (score 1):

You can use continuity from above: if $\nu$ is a finite measure on $(X,\mathcal A)$ and $A_n \searrow \emptyset$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \nu(A_n) = 0$. In this case, since $f \in L^1(\mu)$, the set function
$$ \nu(A) = \int_A f^+ \, d\mu$$ is a finite measure so you have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f^+ \, d\mu = 0.$$ Likewise you have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f^- \, d\mu = 0$$ so the result follows right away.

Comment: You need monotone convergence to establish that $\nu$ is a countably additive measure in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough....